# browsing to AD domain displays sysvol from remote DC

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, sysvol

Five-site company connected with low-latency layer 2 or IPSec tunnels, 2 DCs at each site.

I have noticed that browsing to \\domain.tld often displays sysvol/netlogon shares from a remote DC.  The reason I can tell is because a couple of the smaller sites have DCs that also run print management; the printer shares are displayed there as well.

Pinging domain.tld from a desktop at the HQ site often resolves to a remote DC's IP address.  ipconfig /flushdns then pinging domain.tld again always seems to cause the workstation to resolve the domain name to a different DC, often one at the local site.

To be clear, this isn't causing a problem that I know of, I'm just trying to understand why DNS is behaving this way.  %logonserver% seems to always resolve to a local DC regardless of which DC returns my pings for domain.tld.

Latency between sites is sub-10ms and bandwidth is > 50 Mbps synchronous.

Thanks very much for reading!

> UPDATE: Round Robin is enabled for each DNS server under DNS -> (right
>   click DNS server name) -> Properties -> Advanced -> "Enable round
>   robin."  In addition, in DNS - > (server name) -> Fwd Lookup Zone ->
>   domain.tld, I see name server entries ("same as parent folder") for
>   each domain controller in the forest.  There are also A record with
>   name "(same as parent folder)" for each DC.  I am thinking this
>   behavior is expected, can anyone verify my assumption is correct?

Comment: It sounds like AD Sites and Services isn't setup completely or correctly with your sites and your subnets.

Comment: Sites & Svcs appears to be complete - all sites and subnets appear to be defined correctly.

Comment: Hmmm... I was thinking about the DC Locator Process, I'm not sure that applies to Sysvol. This is probably a case for Netmask Ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DNS Round Robin* is a load-balancing technique, while *DNS Netmask Ordering* provides proximity awareness.

Your DNS servers, by default, will use a Class C subnet mask to determine what records are local to a client. Round-robin will then load-balance your clients across those local results.

Without netmask ordering, your DNS server will send any matching A record randomly, regardless if it is a local address to the client. This sounds like what you are experiencing.

So, **first we need to make sure Netmask Ordering is enabled on your DNS servers.**

1. Open DNS Management Console
2. Right-Click your DNS server and choose `Properties`.
3. Click the `Advanced` tab
4. Make sure `Enable Netmask Ordering` is checked. You can also disable/enable round-robin here, as well.

Next, **make sure your `LocalNetPriorityNetmask` matches your network topology.** Your server, by default, will use a class C Netmask. In other words, it will determine which A records are local to a client by comparing the first 3 octets of the two IP addresses. If your sites use a Netmask smaller or larger than 255.255.255.0, an adjustment has to be made.

1. Open an Administrative Command Prompt
2. Issue the following command: `Dnscmd /Config /LocalNetPriorityNetMask 0x000000FF` to set it back to default. Or adjust the Netmask to meet your needs.

If your site subnet mask is `255.255.0.0` then use a priority mask of `0x0000FFFF`. If your site subnet mask is `255.255.255.192` then use a priority mask of `0x0000003F`. Make sure you set a mask that covers ALL subnets at the site, so all computers at that site get A records local to that site.

I prefer to use group policy to enforce these settings on all my domain controllers. That can be done by directly modifying the parameters found in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters
```

Look for:

- `LocalNetPriority` to enable/disable Netmask ordering.
- `LocalNetPriorityNetmask` to set the mask value.

If you modify the registry to set these options, you’ll need to restart your DNS service for the changes to take affect.

More information here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/842197/description-of-the-netmask-ordering-feature-and-the-round-robin-featur

Comment: Thanks very much for such a thorough answer.  I learned a lot!